# How do programs interface with graphics libraries?

Tags: graphics

I want to make my own image format and a library to read it.

I've tried multiple times to get this info out of people, they all said "go study one of the existing graphics SDKs" and I did and it taught me nothing, it just taught me how to use Open GL... that's not what I wanted. I want to know the inner workings that happen when a program opens an image, so I can handle this operation manually in my own library.

I've studied multiple image formats, I know how the information in them is constructed, but after the program opens them it has to know how to convert them into an RGBA array, right? that's where the graphics library comes in I assume?

The graphics library is a list of instructions for how to read an image as an array of hexidecimal colors I assume? so really I have 3 questions and I hope I am making them clear:

1: What happens in a program when it is presented with an image file? for example does it look for a graphics library with that file extension as it's name (and where?), then read the rules for converting that into a list of color values? or is it converting it directly into machine code and storing it in memory?

2: If I wrote one of these graphics libraries, how would I go about making sure programs can find it? Typically (given an example of an image editor or a game engine, or windows picture preview etc.) does a program automatically see new image libraries or would I need to modify the program to know it exists? (this answer will let me know how much of a hassle it'll be)

3: Is there some standard data format that all graphics applications store image color data in?

Comment: Applications usually have a defined set of image formats they can read. For these, they either use libraries (that they ship with their application and link up in advance) or write some custom code. How those libraries look like depends a lot on what the image format supports. A common way is to have a function that takes a path and returns an array of pixel values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Although file extension may be used by some programs, most will look at the header data. Most formats have some kind of header that gives information that determines how the information will be processed, so the library may be asked, "Does the header of this file look like a kind of file you can access?"

Here is an example of the library used to decode png files used by many programs, including Gimp: https://sourceforge.net/p/libpng/code/ci/master/tree/png.c

It returns color data in the form of 32 bit integers called png_int_32. On the bottom of this page you can see a list of libraries used by Gimp to decode various image formats: https://www.gimp.org/source/#gimp-source-code

2: Some programs are hard coded to use specific libraries and can't be extended with new formats. Larger graphics programs, like Photoshop or Gimp, use plugins. You would have to create plugins that use your library for the programs that you want to support. Here's how to create a Gimp plugin: https://developer.gimp.org/writing-a-plug-in/1/index.html

Here's how to create a Photoshop plugin: https://www.adobe.io/apis/creativecloud/photoshop.html

It takes extra effort to make a program extensible like those programs, so many don't bother. You will only be able to use your libraries in programs that support plugins or are open source, so you can add your library to your own version of that program.

3: Storing image data in 32 bit ints is fairly standard. Easy to use, easy to align in memory, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> 1: What happens in a program when it is presented with an image file?

It will generally ask the operating system to decode the image. The operating system will likely have a number of  libraries that it uses just as [LibTIFF](http://libtiff.org),  [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html), [libjpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg), etc.

By using the operating system instead of directly trying to read image files, applications get the benefits of the OS using the most up-to-date versions of the libraries. So if you write an app today and don't update it again, 5 years from now, it might be able to read a newer version of a given file format if it uses the OS to do so.

> for example does it look for a graphics library with that file extension as it's name (and where?), then read the rules for converting that into a list of color values?

Generally there's a higher-level interface that the OS provides. For example, on macOS, there's [CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics), and [ImageIO](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_basics/ikpg_basics.html).

> or is it converting it directly into machine code and storing it in memory?

There's no machine code involved in image files. (Well, not usually. I'm sure someone has done it somewhere.) Image files store only data, usually in a straightforward way. The library can decompress and/or decode the data and at that point you have something that is likely RGBA (or a variation like ARGB, or BGRA), or YCbCr, or something similar. The OS may make further conversions to get the exact data type the caller requested.

> 2: If I wrote one of these graphics libraries, how would I go about making sure programs can find it?

Usually there's a way to register your image codec with the operating system so that it will be available to programs. This varies by OS.

> Typically (given an example of an image editor or a game engine, or windows picture preview etc.) does a program automatically see new image libraries or would I need to modify the program to know it exists? (this answer will let me know how much of a hassle it'll be)

That varies by program. Some only allow specific formats, some will use any format the OS supports. Some additionally add support for other formats not typically supported by the OS. Photoshop, for example, allows developers to write their own image importers and exporters. If the user has your importer/exporter installed, they get the functionality, otherwise they don't (unless the OS supports it).

> 3: Is there some standard data format that all graphics applications store image color data in?

There are a few common ones - .png, .jpg, and .tif are all widely supported. Even .psd (Photoshop) files are handled in many cases, though not all features work in all cases.